# How to check if dictionary has unwanted keys?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

- Keys that must be in dict
- Keys that are optional for dict

  1. how can I check if the keys that must be there in a dictionary are there or not?
  2. how can I check if any of the optional keys is there in the dictionary or not?

Comment: hey thats nice..!! my name came up on the edit for the first time!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [dictionary views](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) and sets:

```
missing = set(required) - some_dict.viewkeys()
optional_present = some_dict.viewkeys() & optional
```

Sets, like dictionaries, make membership testing cheap and fast, and set operations make it easy to test if items are present or not. You really want to make `required` and `optional` be sets to starts with.

For example, [subtraction on sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) calculates the difference, so `missing` is set to the difference between the `required` list and what keys are in the dictionary.

Using the [`&` operator on sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) (normally binary AND) gives you the intersection, so `optional_present` gives you what keys in the dictionary are also in the `optional` sequence (doesn't have to be a set in this case, but using a set there would make sense).

For testing individual keys you can still use `key in some_dict`, but using set operations avoids excessive looping.

Note that [`dict.viewkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) is  specific to Python (added in Python 2.7); in Python 3, the dictionary enumeration methods [`.keys()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), [`.values()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and [`.items()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) return dictionary views by default and the `.view*()` methods are gone.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in Py3k `dict.keys()` works like `dict.viewkeys()` which no longer exists

Comment: The first line, the subtraction, looks backwards. Wouldn't you want to subtract/remove "required" from the dict? Meaning: `missing = some_dict.view() - set(required)` (Python3 syntax)

Comment: @ahogen: no, because then you get the keys that are *extra*, over and on top of the required keys. You want all keys that are in the `required` set, but which are not in the dictionary, which is what the expression in my answer achieves.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key in your_dict` for the first case and set difference will solve the second one. Dicts can behave like sets using `dict.viewkeys()` (`dict.keys()` in py3x):

You can use `all()` to check if all the keys in a list are present in a dict.

```
all(key in your_dict for key in keys)
```

Set difference:

```
your_dict.viewkeys() - set(keys)
```